# General Solution of ODE: $y'' + y = e^x + 3^x + \sin x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The question asks for general solution of de.

$y'' + y = e^x + 3^x + \sin x$

I guess it is  2. order linear non-homogeneous equation but not sure?

Comment: That is true.   Do you know the method of variation of constants?

Comment: Have you done the homogeneous case, or with just e^x on the RHS? Thanks to linearity, you can solve the simpler problems first and then put them together.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters

Comment: First ignore the x terms. After solving the homogenous ODE, apply variation of parameters to get the solution of the non-homogenous ODE

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

The solution of the equation with no right hand side is
$$y_h=A\sin(x)+B\cos(x)$$
you should add to it a particular solution of the complete equation.

It is a linear equation, you just need particular solution for each of the three terms in right side, and the sum them.

This technic is know as the superposition principle.